# ¿Cómo generar variable que indique el máximo dado el valor de otras variables?

Tags: r, dataframe

Si tengo el siguiente data frame:

```
a<-sample(c("A", "B", "C"), 50, T)
b<-sample(c(2010:2020), 50, T)
d<-sample(1:10, 50, T)
e<-sample(1000:5000, 50, T)

df<-data.frame(a,b,d,e)
df
```

```
   a    b  d    e
1  C 2018  3 4458
2  B 2011  1 2870
3  C 2012 10 4262
4  C 2011  1 2803
5  A 2015  7 4638
6  A 2016 10 2525
7  B 2010  4 1779
8  B 2018  8 1084
9  A 2016  4 2401
10 A 2015  3 3308
11 B 2017  4 4410
12 C 2017  3 1882
13 C 2020  4 2944
14 A 2017  2 1722
15 B 2014  3 4607
16 B 2011 10 4768
17 C 2011  3 4987
18 A 2016  9 3916
19 C 2010  2 3237
20 A 2020  5 3422
21 A 2011  1 4959
22 A 2016 10 3097
23 B 2017  2 1906
24 A 2010  4 3621
25 B 2015 10 2606
26 B 2018  6 3892
27 B 2010  5 3759
28 B 2018  7 4247
29 B 2018  8 1523
30 C 2016  3 4817
31 C 2017  9 3350
32 C 2018  1 1711
33 B 2014  1 3695
34 A 2010  1 3184
35 A 2019  5 4451
36 A 2019 10 4535
37 A 2010  7 4926
38 C 2014  2 3750
39 B 2017 10 4187
40 B 2010  5 2756
41 A 2014  2 4466
42 C 2017  2 3538
43 C 2016  5 3823
44 C 2019  3 2895
45 C 2019  9 1290
46 A 2016  7 2715
47 C 2014  2 3898
48 B 2012 10 4126
49 A 2015  1 3755
50 A 2013  3 4545
```

Cómo puedo hacer para generar una variable, en el data frame, que me indique el valor máximo de `b` dado los valores de la variable `a` y `d`. Es decir, encontrar el b máximo por las variables `a y d`.

En el ejemplo, el valor máximo para `b` si `a` toma "B" y `d` toma 10 será de 2017.

**Muchas gracias de antemano**

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con el paquete `tidyverse` es realmente sencillo. En primer lugar, podemos agrupar por las variables `a` y `d` y obtener el máximo de `b` para cada grupo:

```
library("tidyverse")

df %>% 
  group_by(a,d) %>%        # agrupamos
  summarise(b=max(b)) %>%  # Obtenemos el máximo de b
  print(n = Inf)           # Esto es opcional, solo para mostrar todos los resultados

# A tibble: 24 x 3
# Groups:   a [3]
   a         d     b
   <chr> <int> <int>
 1 A         1  2015
 2 A         2  2017
 3 A         3  2015
 4 A         4  2016
 5 A         5  2020
 6 A         7  2016
 7 A         9  2016
 8 A        10  2019
 9 B         1  2014
10 B         2  2017
11 B         3  2014
12 B         4  2017
13 B         5  2010
14 B         6  2018
15 B         7  2018
16 B         8  2018
17 B        10  2017
18 C         1  2018
19 C         2  2017
20 C         3  2019
21 C         4  2020
22 C         5  2016
23 C         9  2019
24 C        10  2012
```

Si solo nos interesa un determinado grupo, podemos "filtrarlo", en este caso, antes del `group_by()` para reducir el trabajo de este último:

```
df %>% 
  filter(a=="B" & d==10) %>% 
  group_by(a,d) %>% 
  summarise(b=max(b))

# A tibble: 1 x 3
# Groups:   a [1]
  a         d     b
  <chr> <int> <int>
1 B        10  2017
```

Lo mismo mediante R base, se puede resolver también mediante la función `aggregate()` y una simple operación de selección:

```
aggregate(b ~ a + d, df[df$a == "B" & df$d == 10,], max)
```

La notación `b ~ a + d` es una formula para indicar como operará el agrupamiento, en este caso se agrupa por `a` y `d` y la variable dependiente será `b` a la que le aplicaremos la función indicada en el tercer parámetro (`max()`)

Comment: Gracias estimado Patricio, pero en ¿R base como sería?. Me faltó especificar ese detalle, perdón. 

Podría ayudarme por favor

Comment: @CESARHUAMANININAHUANCA, ok, ahí agregué el código

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio.